# How to change param name when uploading file using Vue2-Dropzone?

Tags: vue.js, vue2-dropzone

When uploading file in Vue2-Dropzone, default param name is "file".
But I need to customize it as "upload".

I tried to change it using vdropzone-sending method.
But It sends two params "file" and "upload".

Do I need to change backend to accept the param "file"? or Is there a way to customize default param name("file")?

```
<vue-dropzone v-on:vdropzone-sending="sendingEvent">
</vue-dropzone>
...
methods: {
  sendingEvent (file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('upload', file);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue2-Dropzone is a wrapper around Dropzone.js, which has an option to [change the parameter name](https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-paramName)

In order to pass that option to the Vue2-Dropzone component, you use the [options prop](https://rowanwins.github.io/vue-dropzone/docs/dist/#/props) like so:

```
<vue-dropzone :options="dropzoneOptions" v-on:vdropzone-sending="sendingEvent"></vue-dropzone>
...
data () {
    return {
        dropzoneOptions: { paramName: "upload" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on your answer, I found the all configurations for Dropzone.js.
https://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-paramName